# What is the correct annotation configuration for Spring data and neo4j

Tags: spring-annotations, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to configure Spring-data with Neo4j with an `@configuration` class but I cannot find any reference material on how to do that properly and I'm running into one issue after the next. Here's what I've pieced together so far:

```
package reservation.configuration;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepositoryFactory;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext;

@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("reservation.repository.neo4j")
public class Neo4jConfig {

    private static final String STORE_ID = "helloworld";

    @Bean
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(STORE_ID);
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate() {
        return new Neo4jTemplate(graphDatabaseService());
    }

    @Bean
    public GraphRepositoryFactory graphRepositoryFactory() {
        return new GraphRepositoryFactory(neo4jTemplate(), neo4jMappingContext());
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jMappingContext neo4jMappingContext() {
        return new Neo4jMappingContext();
    }
}
```

The exception I have when starting the application is this below. Any suggestions?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence exception translators found in bean factory. Cannot perform exception translation.
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.<init>(TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:66)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.setBeanFactory(TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:589)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1043)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5279)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to get it down to this after extending from `Neo4jConfiguration`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("reservation.repository.neo4j")
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    private static final String DB_PATH = "/Temp/neo4j";

    @Bean
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(DB_PATH);
    }
}
```

And this seems to work just fine.

Comment: Works! For version spring-data-neo4j:3.2.0.RELEASE try this:
return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseDB_PATH);